# Browser pages won't load Chrome and Firefox after Java SDK install

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, java

For weeks now, Facebook doesn't load properly. Just texts flushed to the left of the screen. Recently, it loaded well. Then back to overlapping texts.
[image]

Forbes.com doesn't load.
Youtube videos don't load either.

[image]

I thought maybe the internet connection is the issue but our neighbor could load facebook just fine.
Also, adult sites load well, especially the videos.

The significant event that happened before these was when I used eclipse and installed java sdk 7 and java 7 update.

Please help me with this.

**Edit:** Windows 7. In Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 and Firefox 25.0
Twitter load well.

**Edit:** January 17 2014, and they still don't load.

Comment: yah. i tried but it requires 10 reps.

Comment: now, youtube won't load the page.

Comment: oh yah. yah. sorry. I'll do it now.

Comment: pic.twitter.com/LKFNu4ESon --facebook

Comment: pic.twitter.com/55bPUwsQq1 --youtube.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is no longer reproducible and has been abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your host file (%System Drive%\System32\Drivers\etc) is clean and do not contain any malicious mapping.

Comment: how would i know if there's any malicious mapping?

Comment: just full of adobe.com